# When is there a $y\in \mathbb{D}\subset \mathbb{C}$ such that $|f(x)-f(0)|/|x| =|f'(y)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\mathbb{D}$ be the unit disk in $\mathbb{C}$. If $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$, does it follow that for each $x\in D$, there is some $y\in D$ such that $|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}|=|f'(y)|$. I know that this does not hold without the absolute value signs. The most direct analogue of the mean value theorem that we have for holomorphic functions in the plane states that there are points $u,v$ (which could be different) where the equality holds for the real part at $u$ and for the imaginary part at $v$. That is $\Re\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right)=\Re(f'(u))$ and $\Im\left(\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\right)=\Im(f'(v))$ But it seems to me that this should imply that somewhere (I'm guessing at a point on the closed triangle connecting $x, u,$ and $v$) there must be a point $y$ where $|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}|=|f'(y)|$

Is this the case? If so, how can it be proved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's false. Try using $f(z)=e^{4\pi z}$. Note that $f(0)=f(i/2)$.

**COMMENT**: This is why the mean value theorem becomes an inequality for vector-valued functions and not an equality.